# How to Select Multiple Row and Store that Values into the Array

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have jtable i want select multiple row and get that values into the Array.how i suppose to do that

My jTable

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjSEE.png]

Comment: Step 1, research the Java Tutorial and get some ideas. Step 2, try something. If it fails, go to step 3, which is, post a [mcve] of your attempt and ask a *specific* question. - SO is not a help desk, nor a code generation machine, Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

> i want select multiple row

This is supported by default in a JTable. You just hold the "Ctrl" key when you click on other rows.

> get that values into the Array

What values?

If you just want the row that is selected you use the `getSelectedRows()` method of the `JTable`.

If you want the data of the selected rows then you use the above method and create a loop and use the `getValueAt(...)` method to get the data from each cell.

Edit:

> when i select check box in first column i want to get EMP ID in that checked row

So usually you have a "Process Selected Rows" button on the form. Then when you click the button you loop through the TableModel and use the getValueAt(...) method to check if the first column is selected. If it is selected then you do your processing.

Comment: when i  select check box in first column i want to get EMP ID in that checked row.i cant use CTRL key becuse this is my Project work

Answer (score 0):

Its required to allow multiple selection by

```
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

Then you can write list selection Lister like this example

[Listner Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Comment: table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);  i use this method but when i use this Error occured Error :incompatible type:int cannot be Conveted ListSelectionModel how can i slove that